# After installing magento my admin login page is blank

Tags: admin

After installing magento 2 my admin login page and home page is not showing what is the problem i dont know what to do because i am begginer

Comment: change the following line in app/bootstrap.php, It will show you the exact error. ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  These type already answered here so please search all those and try to sort out issue. If those dont work then post question here because it will be duplicate and your stands under duplicate post.